# ASP.NET MVC4 with MEF: Requests to MEF Controllers Processed Serially

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, mef

We have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that allows for "modules" (a package of one or more controllers, views, etc.) to be dynamically loaded via MEF. These modules are located, directory-wise, beneath the host's base directory in a folder called Modules. The directory hierarchy looks like this:

```
/MVC_MEF_Host
    /bin
    /obj
    /Scripts
    /Views
    /Modules
        /Module1
            /bin
            /Scripts
            /Views
        /Module2
            /bin
            /Scripts
            /Views
        /Module3
            ...
```

However, we have run into a strange behavior. Requests that come in against a controller that is part of a module (i.e. residing within a module's /bin/ directory) are processed sequentially, while requests made against controllers whose assemblies reside in the host application's /bin/ directory are processed in parallel (which is what we expect).

The strange part is, I'm not sure how the application can tell the difference between the two. Controllers in the host assembly are exported just like the assemblies in the modules. All controllers are exported with `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]`. We use a custom controller factory to instantiate controllers. The only difference between the two types of controller is that the module controllers are located in the module's /bin/ directory instead of in the host's /bin/ directory.

There is some kind of special treatment going on behind the scenes. We set up several tests to determine the origin of this issue. We found that even though our custom controller factory *should* be the first place our application even considers which assembly to pull a controller from, the requests made against module controllers come in sequentially before our controller factory is even called. In other words, even before we have consulted the composition container to determine a controller to use, the calls are made sequentially. When the requests target a controller whose assembly resides within the host /bin/, the calls to the controller factory are made in parallel.

We have considered several workarounds (the currently leading one being copying the module assemblies into the host's /bin/) but each of the workarounds has a serious drawback that impacts our intended workflow.

I have included a trimmed-down version of our method that performs composition, in case this is a side effect of something we're doing during composition.

```
static void _Compose(List<string> moduleDirectories)
{
    ResetViewEngine(moduleDirectories);         // adds the modules' /Views/ paths to the view engine

    AggregateCatalog aggCat = new AggregateCatalog();

    // Load host bin directory
    aggCat.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin")));

    foreach (string pluginPath in moduleDirectories)
    {
        string modulePath = Path.Combine(pluginPath, "bin");

        if (Directory.Exists(modulePath))
        {
            // Add directory to private paths, required for plugin dependencies                                   
            #pragma warning disable 618
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(modulePath);  // this is obsolete, but since we're not constructing an appDomain...
            #pragma warning restore 618

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(modulePath, PLUGIN_FILENAME_PATTERN))
            {
                Assembly asm = LoadAssemblyFromFile(file);      // reads the bytes of the assembly into memory and then loads via Assembly.Load()

                if (asm != null)
                {
                    AssemblyCatalog ac = new AssemblyCatalog(asm);
                    aggCat.Catalogs.Add(ac);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log("Could not load assembly: " + file);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log("Module path " + modulePath + " does not exist.");
        }
    }

    // partsContainer is a private static member of our PartsBootstrapper class
    partsContainer = new CompositionContainer(aggCat, true);
    partsContainer.ComposeParts();
}
```

So, how can I get requests for module controllers to be processed in parallel like the requests for controllers within the host's /bin/ are?

Comment: As a note, we export our controllers using their name as the contract name. Our custom controller factory calls a method within our `PartsBootstrapper` class to retrieve the controller with the controller name, which in turn calls `partsContainer.GetExportedValue<IController>(contractName)`, where `partsContainer` is our `CompositionContainer` and `contractName` is the controller name.

Comment: Another note for more context: we discovered this issue when attempting to make several long-running AJAX calls in parallel to actions within a module's controller. We expected that the requests would be processed in parallel (in whatever batches were sent by the browser). Instead, we found that although the browser properly batched the AJAX calls and sent them off, our application would handle one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this in the future, we found a solution. I don't necessarily understand why it works, but it does seem to work.

Essentially, our custom controller factory was inheriting from `DefaultControllerFactory`. We were relying on the default implementation of the `GetControllerSessionBehavior` method, which as it turns out is always SessionStateBehavior.Default. By changing our controller factory to instead inherit from `IControllerFactory`, we were able to define our own implementation of `GetControllerSessionBehavior`.

We had our implementation return `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` but this was not sufficient. MVC was preventing us from writing to session at all, despite what we had read about it actually allowing session writes when the session state behavior was ReadOnly (and just falling back to a `SessionStateBehavior.Required` status). So, we added a new `ExportMetadata` that allows us to specify the `SessionStateBehavior` for the `GetControllerSessionBehavior` method, and this seems to work. Now, we default to `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` unless the metadata has a different behavior specified.

We still don't really understand why assemblies within the host's /bin/ were treated differently than module assemblies, but this solution works for us.